# Python: How do I remove the + at the end?

Tags: python

When I type a number, for example, 3, I want the output to be 1+2+3, not 1+2+3+, how do I fix that?

```
number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
for i in range(1, number + 1):
    print(i, end="+")
```

Answer (score 6):

One easy way is to use `join` instead of repeated `print` statements.

```
print('+'.join(str(i) for i in range(1, number + 1)))
```

Or using `map` instead of `for`:

```
print('+'.join(map(str, range(1, number + 1))))
```

Comment: Yep, just as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52820342/6045800) from the duplicate already suggests....

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
for i in range(1, number + 1):
    if i == number:
        print(i)
    else:
        print(i, end="+")
```

Comment: Why not just iterate until one number less instead of checking a condition on ***every*** iteration?

Comment: Well it has been kinda lot of time I haven't touched Python so I did the first thing that passed in my mind.